# Simple model-dialog for my ASP.Net MVC web app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, showdialog

I need a solution for a simple model-dialog for my ASP.Net MVC web app.

I used the window.open but it looks too big for some small Grid data dialogs. IE supports showModelDialog - none of the other browsers do.

I've two types of dialogs:

> 1. Simple Grid or readonly data (i.e. no postback)
> 2. Both Grid + Data entry (and one even has a file-upload)

I visited some jQ dialogs and most of them need to load the content inline - I need something dynamic which loads content only if the dialog is invoked. And also able to perform postback and refresh (without refreshing the parent page).

I opted iframes long ago after some SO guys said too many things about it - that it is too old. Otherwise I'd have loaded the content in iframes when requested and then used one of the many jQ dialogs which are based on inline content rendering. I hope some one will help me out with a simple solution because my pages are already packed with multiple ajax calls - this one needs to be as simple as possible.

Thank you.

*PS: Can this work - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's quite old and I must say someone would have grabbed this one liner -

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

This one's got all of it and more !